# INSERTING datas into table doesn't work,why?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to insert data into table sortiranje1 after I have done with my first $sql statement. For some reason, there are no inserted records into table sortiranje1. Also there are no errors.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM komentari WHERE IDteksta=$b and Tip='vest' and Dodaj='da'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$zbir=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $zbir=$zbir+$row['Rezultat'];
}
//echo "zbir lajkova je " . $zbir . " a indeks vesti je " . $b; 



$upis = "INSERT INTO sortiranje1 (IDteksta)             
    VALUES ('$b')";
```

Also, like you can see I have echo that var $b, and it's ok, but I have no idea why it's not inserted into table! Here is my code for table:

```
$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($conn,'neprodaji');
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sortiranje1 (
    ID INT(9) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    IDteksta INT(9) NOT NULL,
    Rezultat INT(9) NOT NULL)";
```

Comment: try `echo $upis;` and execute the SQL in your DB directly. That should show you if an error happens.

Comment: You never call `mysqli_query($conn, $upis)`

Comment: Where you execute your insert query?

Comment: you write insert query but not executed it. execute it by calling  `mysqli_query($conn, $upis)` just after insert query

Comment: TY, i cna belive i miised that line! Now pls explane to me how to rate your comment cuz i am pretty new at posting coments here, i read a lot, but this is my first intro :). Ty again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem you are facing because you are not executing your insert query, so write this line after insert query:-

```
mysqli_query($conn, $upis);
```

Note:- if you want to put some check (condition) based on this insert query then assign it to a variable like `$result = mysqli_query($conn, $upis);` and use that variable for check. it will be Boolean type.

Comment: Yes, i missed that. i saw your comment already, all is good now, ty again! When i reach 15 reputations, ill vote your answer, like i said i am pretty knew here although i read this forum a lot! Regards...

Comment: But you can mark it as an answer. for others to get help from this. So mark as an answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

`IDteksta` is an integer field - but by using quotes, you turn it into a string. just remove the quotes:

```
INSERT INTO sortiranje1 (IDteksta)             
VALUES ($b)
```

Comment: MySQL will automatically convert strings to numbers.

Comment: @Barmar nope, not if you use quotes.

Comment: wow, didn't know that. that's pretty dumb on mysql's part. and nice downvote, bro!

Comment: It's no dumber than scripting languages like Javascript, Perl, and PHP that automatically convert between strings and numbers as necessary.

Comment: that's a dumb comparison because MySQL got strict datatypes where PHP or Javascript doesn't have them. in PHP you can save a string in a variable that just contained an integer - but try saving the string 'nuts' to a mysql-integer-field...